# Coldfusion: SELECT FROM QoQ WHERE X in (SELECT Y FROM QoQ) not working

Tags: sql, coldfusion, qoq

In CF I am trying to do a QoQ where the rows are in a list of other rows. Basically moving some code from cftags to cfscript (Not important why). In tags we have a main query and we have several  nests that do some heavy lifting. I am moving this to cfscript and have the following syntax that is working:

```
var submissionList = new Query(dbtype="query", QoQsrcTable=ARGUMENTS.answers, sql="
SELECT submission_id FROM QoQsrcTable GROUP BY submission_id
").execute().getResult();
var submissions = new Query(dbtype="query", QoQsrcTable=ARGUMENTS.answers, sql="
    SELECT * FROM QoQsrcTable WHERE submission_id IN (#submissionList.submission_id#)
").execute().getResult();
```

I have tried the following but it fails to work:

```
var submissions = new Query(dbtype="query", QoQsrcTable=ARGUMENTS.answers, sql="
    SELECT * FROM QoQsrcTable WHERE submission_id IN (SELECT submission_id FROM QoQsrcTable GROUP BY submission_id)
").execute().getResult();
```

I think the second example should work. I've tried messing with it in various ways. But can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong. Maybe a nested QoQ doesn't work like that. Is there another way I can accomplish what I am trying without two chunks of code? Just so it's more readable and I don't have to assign variables twice.

Comment: I cannot stick around, but it would help to clarify what you mean by *fails to work*. An error occurs, zero results, ..?

Comment: Error. Gives me something similar to "Syntax error at "submission_id IN (SELECT submissions_id" expected condition [like|in|between]" blah blah

Comment: can you post the full error message?

Comment: Either you're not showing us everything, or you've got a convoluted set of code that does `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Arguments.answers` ?

Comment: Your query makes no sense!  You're selecting all the entries in the Answers table.  Then you're selecting all the entries from the Answers table where the submission_id is in the list you just selected.  So you're getting everything a second time?  Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Following from Duncan, if this is your actual code, then it's not the best way of accomplishing your task. Could you clarify this point please.

Answer (score 3):

QoQ doesn't support subqueries.  That's the long and the short of it.

[Docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0e4fd-7ff9.html)

Comment: As Adam said, QoQ doesn't support sub queries but you can use in (#valuelist(someOtherQuery.columnName)#)

Comment: I just used @Travis' idea today. Break out the subquery into it's own QoQ, save the values with `<cfset myList = ValueList(QoQ2.column))>` then I used `where xxx in (#PreserveSingleQuotes(myList)#)`

Comment: @djailer - You should not need `PreserveSingleQuotes`. Just use `cfqueryparam` with the `list` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

In Coldfusion 10 or Railo 4, you can utilize the [groupBy function](http://russplaysguitar.github.com/UnderscoreCF/#groupBy) of [Underscore.cfc](http://russplaysguitar.github.com/UnderscoreCF/) to accomplish what you want in much less code:

```
_ = new Underscore();// instantiate the library    

submissions = _.groupBy(arguments.answers, 'submission_id');
```

`groupBy()` returns a structure where the keys are the values of the group element (in this case, `submission_id`).

(Disclaimer: I wrote Underscore.cfc)